# SQLite - GROUP BY rows, only when certain columns match another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am building a schedule app, which uses a predefined API from my school. Each lesson has it's times declared for each hour in a single row. A short example:

Table lessons:

```
Subject         Id      Start       End

English         111     09:30       10:30
English         111     10:30       11:30
Dutch           120     12:30       13:30
Java            109     14:30       15:30
English         111     15:30       16:30
```

To retrieve the lessons, and to show them inside my app, I use the following query:

```
SELECT MIN(start), MAX(end) FROM lessons ORDER BY Start GROUP BY Id
```

It works pretty well, however when a student has the same two lessons with the same Id on a day, in this case `English`, the SQL query will show it as:

```
English 09:30 - 16:30
```

In this case we have a problem, since English doesn't take 6 hours, and I want to show it as:

```
English 09:30 - 11:30
English 15:30 - 16:30
```

So my question is:
What query should I use to only `GROUP BY` lessons when the `start` or `end` values equals another row with the same id, to avoid wrong times?, I could do this programmaticly but I really prefer to do this using SQL.

EDIT:

I am grouping by, because I don't want to show each lesson as a seperate row, because my school defines every lessonhour as a single row.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my school returns everything as a JSON dump. I parse everything to an Android SQLite database.

Comment: I makes no sense. Why are you grouping in the first place?

Comment: Do we have only 2 adjacent lessons at most?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz no it can be more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job

```
with        cte as
            (
                select      subject,id,start,end
                from        mytable t   
                where       not exists 
                            (
                                select      null 
                                from        mytable t2
                                where       t2.id  = t.id
                                        and t2.end = t.start
                            )      

                union all

                select      t.subject,t.id,cte.start,t.end

                from                    cte     
                            join        mytable t
                            on          t.id    = cte.id
                                    and t.start = cte.end
            )

select      subject,id,start,max(end) as end

from        cte   

group by    subject,id,start
```

---

```
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
| subject | id  | start | end   |
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
| Dutch   | 120 | 12:30 | 13:30 |
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
| English | 111 | 09:30 | 11:30 |
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
| English | 111 | 15:30 | 16:30 |
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
| Java    | 109 | 14:30 | 15:30 |
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: It might not have be clear but I am using SQLite, I will try this.

Comment: This was tested on SQLite 3.8.11

Comment: Thanks, I had to tweak the query a bit, but there is a small error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION ALL do not have the same number of result columns (code 1);

Comment: This was a working code. I can't assist you if I don't know what changes you made.

Comment: It gives an exception on older Android versions (the WITH statement is the issue), are there any other options?

Comment: We can use a series of left joins but we should decide on the max number of adjucent ranges in advance

Comment: I will try to include the most recent version of SQLite as a library in my app :)

Comment: That should do it... :-)

Comment: Could you find a more lighter query? I use it on Android, but when selecting around 74 rows will freeze the whole app since it's a heavy query.

Comment: It doesn't make sense unless there is a cycle in the data. Do you have a record with the same start  and end?

Comment: No each row is one hour

Comment: Can you send me the data? I'll take a look tomorrow

Comment: Yes! If you can send me some chat message or email, I will send you it as soon as possible. Thanks for your help!